# Log cmdlet output to file with logging function without use of foreach

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a cmdlet like the following example to deleted files older than x days and a logging function (write-log) that logs to a file:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$path = "C:\Some\Path"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

What I want to do is log what the cmdlet does to each processed file. In a normal foreach-loop I would add something like this to log the process

```
if($?){
    write-log -Info "File $item deleted successfully" #call my logging function that logs to a file
} else {
    write-log -Info "File $item could not be deleted" #call my logging function that logs to a file
}
```

How can I log all actions using my logging function and the above cmdlet?

Comment: I should have asked below, why are you avoiding ForEach/ForEach-Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply combine them into the same loop?

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$path = "C:\Some\Path"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Item $_ -Force
    if($?){
        write-log -Info "File $($_.Name) deleted successfully" #call my logging function that logs to a file
    } else {
        write-log -Info "File $($_.Name) could not be deleted" #call my logging function that logs to a file
    }
}
```

Comment: hm thx, didnt think that it could be that easy to turn it into a foreach :/